# Any self learning computers playing chess? How good are they?

Tags: engines

There is another question that asks "Has anyone ever written a chess program that does have insights of its own" I am asking having to learn the rules of the game, pieces, board size, etc. The program should be able to learn any board game, checkers, go, etc. Computers *programmed by humans* are better at chess than humans. *Any computer programmed by itself* (via some self learning algorithm, where even the rules have to be learned, i.e. number of pieces, board dimensions, piece move rules, game objective, etc) playing any good at all? Let's ignore that the self learning algorithm would have been devised by a human...

Comment: Not really a duplicate. Here the computer program has to learn chess or any other game for that matter, not programmed with the rules.

Comment: No this is exactly what asked in the duplicate post.

Comment: No. That question asks "Has anyone ever written a chess program that does have insights of its own" I am asking having to learn the rules of the game, pieces, board size, etc. The program should be able to learn any board game, checkers, go, etc.